# Create Dynamic Json

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi

I want to create a dynamic json from data in database.

My solution in SSMS database as stored procedure but I think it is not the best solution.

The json contains nested json and each part must be created and then put it all together.

Is there a tool can do that or if you have any create solution please go

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.